# How to type a prop that gets rendered as dynamic component HTML Element

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How to type a component, that accepts a valid html element tag name as a prop to render it dynamically

```js
interface ButtonProps {
  children: ReactNode;
  className?: string;
  as?: string; <--- ?
  [key: string]: unknown;
}


const Button = forwardRef({ children, as: Component = 'button', children, ...props}: ButtonProps), ref) => (
  <Component ref={ref} className={className} {...props}>
    {children}
  </Component>

)
```

Currently getting the typescript error `Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.` which makes absolute sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can type it as follows:

```
interface ButtonProps {
  children: ReactNode;
  className?: string;
  as?: string;
  [key: string]: unknown;
}

const Button = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, ButtonProps>(
  (props, ref) => {
    return (
      <Component ref={ref}>
        {props.children}
      </Component>
    );
  }
);

export default Button;
```

First type argument is for `ref` and other type argument is for `props` that's a bit confusing.